# Any way to have workspace/folder settings ONLY apply to files in that workspace/folder and not random files outside the workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know about workspace settings. My issue is that workspace settings also apply to any files that are opened not in that workspace. Example:

- "editor.formatOnSave": true  // put this in some workspace settings.
- open a file not in that workspace (maybe in a different project) in the same window. This happens when I type `$ code ~/someFile.txt`
- When I save that file, it gets formatted when it shouldn't.

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for saving a file without formatting, try [new command for saving without formatting](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_save-without-formatters).  Just added in v1.28.0:

> The new command Save without Formatting
>   (`workbench.action.files.saveWithoutFormatting`) can be used to save a
>   file without triggering any of the save participants (for example,
>   formatters, remove trailing whitespace, final newline). The default
>   keybinding is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd>. This is useful when editing files outside your
>   normal projects, which may have different formatting conventions.